# Swift dataTaskWithUrl Not Working?

Tags: swift

I have simple request.It use to work but I have changed something I don't know what. It's not working now Task is not resuming

```
 let url = "http://www.bla.com";
  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: url)!)
        {
            (data, response, error) in

            if  error != nil
            {
            }
            else
            {
                print(data);
            }


        };


    task.resume();
```

Comment: And My Xcode is  SDK  9.1

Comment: whats the error in console

Comment: No errors its just skipping my code

Comment: try printing something inside error block what if its running your task but returning nil

Comment: Nakib I tried that but I said before Debugger is not going inside the task code block

Comment: Yes Tried that too Still same :(

Comment: Nakib. I've created different project and I use same codes. Its working :) What a silly problem. Is there cache or what I dont understand how can I solve this?